# instantiating a new object in cpp

Tags: c++, class, constructor, new-operator, dynamic-allocation

I have 3 classes called Starter,Pizza and Dessert that takes variable number of string inputs whenever an object is created like,

```
//pizza takes 2 inputs
Pizza p("margarita","large size");

//starter takes 3 inputs
Starter s("ribs","bbq sauce","small size");
```

But I want to create a *new* object using a function add() that takes a string and matches it with the class to create a new object. Eg

```
add(string type)
{
   if(type == "Pizza")
   {
     Pizza *p = new Pizza();
   }

   else if(type == "Starter ")
   {
     Starter *p = new Starter ();
   }
}
```

Now my question is, how can I give the inputs to the classes in a user friendly way? By user friendly I was thinking that the user can write all the inputs of a class in one line and not using cin to take every single input.

Say we are getting Pizza, then what I dont want,

```
cout<<"What type of pizza";
cin>>*input* <<endl;
cout<<"What size";
cin>>*input* <<endl;
```

I want to write all the inputs in one line like,

*input* "margarita","large"

Comment: Do you want to take inputs exactly from stdin? Not from files or  something else?

Comment: it'll be a simple parsing. with use of `getline()`

Comment: at the moment I am using getline to get each input separately, can I get two inputs together using one getline() ? @MubashirHanif

Comment: Yes, I just want to take user input from stdin and not from any files. @maxteneff

Comment: getline() gives you a complete line from the stream so as lon as the user inputs a complete line as an input it'll work fine.. but you have to be sure that the user inputs each and everything into the a line. once you have the line say user inputs the `"margarita","large"` you'll have to tockenize on the basis of the `,` if you are asking user to format the input by putting space into his input `"margarita" "large"` like this then use @MuratKarakus Answer bellow that'll work prety good for you . @SafwanUllKarim

Comment: or if you are not sure about the input see my answer. its just the extension of @MuratKarakus

Comment: Thanks a lot @MubashirHanif. I will try it out and see what happens

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Credit is to @MuratKarakus. just extending his answer to support this type of input `"margarita","large"`

```
// Read complete string.
// Eg. margarita large
string order;
getline(cin, order);

std::replace( order.begin(), order.end(), ',', ' '); // this'll replace all ',' with space

// It automatically parses string based on space
istringstream is(order);
string meal, size;
is >> meal;
is >> size;
```

--------update

The code bellow is to support input like `"1/2 margarita 1/2 bbq delux", "large"`

```
// Read complete string.
// Eg. margarita large
string order;
getline(cin, order);
std::replace( order.begin(), order.end(), ' ', '-'); // this'll replace all space with '-'
std::replace( order.begin(), order.end(), ',', ' '); // this'll replace all ',' with space
// It automatically parses string based on space
istringstream is(order);
string meal, size;
is >> meal;
std::replace( meal.begin(), meal.end(), '-', ' '); // this'll replace all '-' with space

is >> size;
```

Comment: The code worked but in your replace, is there anyway to get rid of the space? As I would also want to take inputs like "1/2 margarita 1/2 bbq delux", "large" @MubashirHanif

Comment: @SafwanUllKarim well for a complete solution the you should give me a complete format of the input user is gonna make..

for the input `"1/2 margarita 1/2 bbq delux", "large"` like this you might wana do dome thing line 2 way replacing first `replace` all the spaces with a known character.. say a `. or -` then use streams to get back parts of the input and parse them accordingly.. I am updating my answer to support your current input spec

Comment: Thanks again! you are a big help @MubashirHanif

Comment: @SafwanUllKarim Mention not dude, Its our duty here to help :D

Answer (score 2):

```
// Read complete string.
// Eg. margarita large
string order;
getline(cin, order);

// It automatically parses string based on space
istringstream is(order);
string meal, size;
is >> meal;
is >> size;
```